# SharePoint Designer Workflow evaluate two conditions

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

here's what I need to do and I'm having trouble doing... I have a SPD workflow that has to do the following:

1. Verify if the added document set is on Folder A

   - Change a field
   - Send an Email
   - Wait on field
   - Send an Email
   - Wait on field
   - Copy Document Set to a different Library
   - Move current item to Folder B (on the original library)
2. Verify if the added document set is on Folder B

   - Change a field
   - Send an Email
   - Wait on field
   - Send an Email
   - Wait on field
   - Move Document Set to a different Library

What I have works fine, It does this great for both items manually added to Folder A than to Folder B, the issue is that I need that once the item that was added to Folder A is moved to Folder B that the 2nd Part executes, instead when it reaches the last step of section 1 SharePoint shows the WF as complete and I would have to re-start it for it to do what I need it to do.

Is there a way to make the WF continue and evaluate the second condition?

Thanks!

Comment: Split workflow, 1. on Folder A and 2. on Folder B

Comment: But is it possible to have a WF attached to a folder instead of a list? If I'm thinking correctly what you are saying is having two separate workflows that both start on Item Added and only the second one on Item Updated. Would that work correctly or would it bring performance issues having the workflow launch on each edit of every single item on the list even if the folder is not the one that the condition asks for? Thanks for your help. You gave me a new perspective on the issue and maybe splitting the WF is the way to go.

Comment: Yes, if you split up the workflow is more simple to think, what is the `Wait on field` operation ? Another approach is to manage a hidden field with workflow status, based on this perform different operation, but is imperative that every time the workflow complete and do not wait any input.

Comment: The Wait on field is the default action "Wait for Field Change in Current Item".